# Manjaro can't install pandoc, invalid or corrupted package

Tags: pacman, pandoc

I tried to install pandoc, but I keep getting the error

```
(106/106) checking package integrity                            [###################################] 100%
error: failed to commit transaction (invalid or corrupted package)
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
```

I have tried updating all the keys and updated the cache, but no luck. 
How can I find out which package is failing to install? Is there a way I can resolve this issue? What should be my next step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Had to delete everything inside /var/cache/pacman/pkg